# Establishing DGPS Communications With SurvCE and Novatel Recievers

Tags: surveying

I am trying to do a differential surveying project with some outdated equipment, specifically:

- An old AllegroCX personal handheld computer (Win 4.1) with SurvCE loaded on it to collect data and establish communication
- Two Novatel ProPak V3 Recievers (one for base, one for rover)
- Two external radio communicators
- Two pinwheel style antennas

I am able to establish a connection with the rover's Novatel reviever and AllegroCX using a serial cable, but I cannot get it to find the base receiver using radio communications. Is this possible wirelessly, or do I need to set up the base station via serial cable as well? Do I need to have a PC connected to the base receiver?